# Default Program With Multiple Versions Installed

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have multiple versions of Excel installed.  Excel 2010, 2007 and 2003.  I have them installed on one hard drive with Windows 7 Ultimate as the OS.

When I double-click on an XLS file, Excel 2007 opens.  I would like Excel 2010 to open.  I read and followed the instructions to go to the Control Panel at "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Default Programs" and set the default programs.   I changed the default to the physical EXE for Excel 2010 at the proper folder that it is installed.

When I double-click on the XLS files, Excel 2007 still opens.  So I tried to change it to Excel 2003 just to see if it changed to that and it still opens Excel 2007.

What am I missing?  I would really like the file extension to open Excel 2010, but can not seem to do that.

**UPDATE:**  I've also investigated Registry settings for this and still cant seem to get Excel 2010 to start as the default program for XLS files.  Not even CSV files, it defaults to Excel 2007..  Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Try registering Excel 2010. Close all versions of Excel then from Start > Run, type your path to Excel 2010:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE14\excel.exe" /regserver
```

and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Note: adjust your path as necessary to find the Excel 2010 executable.

You may also have to unregister Excel 2007:

```
<path to version which is current default, e.g. Office11>\excel.exe /unregserver
```

Alternatively installing in order of version will also help. You will have to uninstall Office 2007 and 2010 completely, then reinstall in order, i.e. 2003 followed by 2010. This should make 2010 the default.

Comment: I dont think that is going to work.  Its not a DLL that needs to be registered.  Uninstalling 2003, 2007, 2010 and then reinstalling them all again is not an option.  I did install them in the increasing version order anyway.

Comment: @OptimalSolutions: [MS KB918957](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918957) details this procedure, but it doesn't work on Office 2007 or 2010.  For those, you need to use the "Repair" option from "Programs & Features" (e.g. Setup/Uninstall) in order to re-register Office 2010 as the default.  Also, see [MS KB2121447](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2121447) on having multiple versions of Office installed.  MS says that they should be installed in release order.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to use multiple versions of excel on single PC.

e.g 2003,2007,2010

Please install them in following order
2003
2007
2010

even after installing in above order , and after sometime you are installing a update for 2007.
then you need to repair all the office verions in following order
2003
2007
2010

By doing this 2010 will be set as your default program.

Answer (score 0):

I´m not 100% sure this helps but in a lot of similar cases i used the tool called extman.
I realy loved the windows xp management for file extentions and since windows 7 its kinda restricted and you need to do the same stuff using regedit.

So just try the tool could work as well.

http://www.extman.com/

Comment: Please be careful posting links in answers of this nature—they could be seen by the community as spam, correctly or otherwise. See the [help/behavior] for more information.